# AWS Codedeploy errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I want to run aws codedeploy-agent on ubuntu machine on premises. I'm getting below error, not able find root cause.

I added the logs for codedeploy-agent file:

```
2023-10-13T07:53:53 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(17254)]: booting child: error during start or run: SystemExit - exit - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:98:in `exit'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:98:in `rescue in with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:85:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:33:in `prepare_run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:64:in `block in prepare_run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:86:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:63:in `prepare_run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:20:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:206:in `block in spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:204:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:204:in `spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:283:in `block (2 levels) in replace_terminated_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/logging-2.2.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:474:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
2023-10-13T07:53:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(16666)]: master 16666: Received CHLD - cleaning dead child process
2023-10-13T07:53:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(16666)]: master 16666: been told to replace child 17254
2023-10-13T07:53:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(16666)]: master 16666: not enough child processes running - missing at least 1 - respawning
```

any suggestion to troubleshoot this problem?